# The role of eigenvalues and eigenvectors in similar matrices

Tags: linear-algebra

I'm learning about similar matrices and I've done problems such as calculating a diagonal matrix $D = C^{-1}AC$, similar to $A$. This involved finding eigenvectors and eigenvalues of $A$.

However, if I took any nonsingular matrix $S$ with compatible dimensions with $A$, wouldn't $S^{-1}AS$ be similar to $A$?

Aside from finding a similar diagonal matrix, I'm having some trouble understanding the role of eigenvectors and eigenvalues in similar matrices. Also, what's the significance of a diagonal matrix similar to some matrix $A$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that if $$C^{-1}AC=D$$ where $D$ is diagonal, then $$ C^{-1}A^kC=D^k$$

that is $$A^k = CD^kC^{-1}$$

Since it is very straight forward to find powers of the diagonal matrix $D$ this process makes finding the powers of $A$ straight forward as well.

Same goes with exponential matrices which are use in solving systems of differential equations.

In terms of eigenvalues, note that a matrix and its similar matrices have the same eigenvalues but they do not necessarily share the same eigenvectors.

Answer (score 1):

You are correct that for any nonsingular matrix S, multiplying matrix A on the left by S inverse and on the right by S would yield a similar matrix to A. The problem is probably intentionally being redundant because describing D in this way makes it easier for you to refer to your result D or the change of basis matrix C.

Finding a diagonal matrix is very important in computing powers of a matrix because raising a diagonal matrix to a power can be performed quickly by simply raising each term to that power, meaning that finding a power of A can be reduced to diagonalizing A, computing the power for the resulting diagonal matrix , and performing the inverse of the change of basis used to diagonalize A.